# Getting thoughts of waswas after kufr

Tags: kufr, waswasa

Assalamualaikum this question is general but closely connected with me my question is does a person who was a victim of waswas get waswas thoughts after he had done kufr or become out of islam
I had seen in some site that waswas show a sign of faith in us and a person will not get waswas after becoming out of islam
If anyone knows it answer please share with me as soon as possible

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: do you consider yourself a muslim or out of islam?

Comment: What is your worries? are you scared you've done an act of Kufr?

Comment: What did you do? Like what is your act

Comment: Why would that be kufr? Kufr means rejecting Islam, verses of the Quran, disbelieving one of the fundamentals of Islam, you did not commit Kufr and STOP listening to shaytan and read the Quran to make your waswas go away

Comment: I asked to allah one day can you please send rain if what I done that day was not kufr it was a sunny day and after few minutes it starts to rain Alhamdulillah

Answer (score 0):

In Arabic, the term kufr literally means covering or concealing something, and in a religious context, it refers to hiding or denying religious truth.([Ref](https://classroom.synonym.com/what-is-kufr-in-islam-12086374.html))

What you did was "take up your feet against the cupboard that has Islamic books". I do not know if it can be regarded as Kufr or not. But i assume it has the word Allah written in the book (since it's an islamic book)? If you have the intention to disrespect Allah 's name, then you may get a sin for that. However as long you didn't have any intention to disrespect, then you wouldn't be hold accountable for that Insha Allah.

Since it happened in the past, and you regret that you did the action, then just repent to Allah for what you did. If you still overthink, then try to recite the Shahada sincerely with full believe of what you recite.

and Allah knows best.